# Why won't the BufferedWriter instantiation write to a txt file in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter, writer

I am trying to instantiate a object with BufferedWriter and it wont work. The problem happens when I use the write function. Why won't it let me write to the file? 
The error is cannot find symbol. Please help me. I know someone knows. Why wont it not find the symbol when this is a bufferedWriter method?

```
package ex5_abcd;

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EX5_ABCD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean go = true;
        String firstN, lastN;
        String lineWritten = "";
        int IdNum;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Java\\empList.txt");
        try {
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file, CREATE));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
            while (go) {
                System.out.println("Please enter Employee's First Name");
                firstN = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter Employee's Last Name");
                lastN = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter " + firstN + " " + lastN);
                IdNum = input.nextInt();
                lineWritten = IdNum + " " + firstN + " " + lastN;
                int lineLength = lineWritten.length();
                char [] testChar  =  new char[1];
            testChar [0] = 'a';
            writer = write(testChar, 0, lineLength); // Why write error
                writer.flush();
                writer.newLine();

            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Msg:" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncomment the flush?

Comment: Still wont work bro and where is the duplicate Sotirios Delimanolis. I'd like to see it sir.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis
Can we un-dupe this, since its not an actual dupe?

Comment: Thought it wasent a dup too.

Comment: I sense myself being offended, do you want the answer or not

Comment: Please provide more details that explain why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I want the answer. I found nothing that explains my situation with what I have here. Which means its not a duplicate.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The answer does not relate to the duplicate in question, rather it is a syntax error

Comment: I'm unconvinced. If you have a compiler error, add it to your question. If there is some other behavior, explain what behavior you expect and why. Then explain what actual behavior you are getting.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It IS a compilation error. It is very simple too, if you (I assume you can) un flag this question, I'll have a opportunity to show you.

Comment: Yes, I can reopen the question. I will do so when OP proves to me, in their question, that it isn't. The question, as it stands, does not contain enough detail.

Comment: It says cannot find symbol. Why?

Comment: That's a bit better. Now a duplicate of [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: I know why the compiler says cannot find symbol. But I am doing every thing correct here with what goes in method. That's the issue here pal.

Comment: Obviously not. Otherwise, you wouldn't get an error. Please just read the question and answer there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Provided answer, should work now.

Comment: @JClassic I suggest you don't answer questions like these. They should be closed as typos or because _this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_. Or closed as a duplicates with a given canonical answer. I realize you don't have the reputation right now, but when you do, that's what you should be doing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok :) I'll be sure. Anyways :P I just didn't want it to be closed as the wrong duplicate

Comment: I agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis. please close this question as typo. It could be misleading for future readers.

Comment: Thanks bro. I learned a lot just now. Thanks and maybe one day I can be great like you are :)

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = write(lineWritten, 0, lineLength);
```

should be rewritten to

```
writer.write(lineWritten, 0, lineLength);
```

since `writer` is not a reference to an object, you should call the method of the writer object, not set `writer` to another value

Recap:

(=) sets a value.

Also, since you never set the value of `go` as false in your loop, you will keep on looping there... forever... and ever....  I suggest to not let that happen